# How can I handle string containing "$" symbol in Julia

Tags: julia, latex

I have extracted a substring from a file containing strings that starts with "$" and I want to replace the `'$'` symbol with "$" so that it looks like `"\$sel:incPreTxn"` and `"\$!"` as I will be later converting it to latex code. Please suggest me how can I handle "$" symbol in Julia.

I tried to use occursin and replace function that also didn't help and got LoadError. `ERROR: LoadError: syntax: invalid interpolation syntax: "$""`

Here is the sample code for reference:

```
str = "$sel:incPreTxn"
 if occursin("$", str)                   
     str = replace(str, "\$:" => "\\$")
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you want to prefix the dollar sign that may be present in a string with a backslash symbol.

As the dollar symbol is "special" in Julia within a string (e.g. it allows interpolation of variables), you need to prefix it with a backlash in Julia too. And because the backlash is "special" too, you need to prefix it with a backlash as well.

This would do the job:

```
julia> str = "\$sel:incPreTxn"
"\$sel:incPreTxn"

julia> str2 = replace(str, "\$" => "\\\$")
"\\\$sel:incPreTxn"
```

While both `str` and `str2` are displayed with 1 and 3 backslash, they are actually with 0 and 1 respectively, as you can see by printing them or saving them to a file:

```
julia> print(str)
$sel:incPreTxn
julia> println(str2)
\$sel:incPreTxn
```